# What happens when a AC current is applied to a PN junction?

Tags: transistors, power-electronics, pn-junction

What would happen if a AC current is applied to a PN junction? Is the input current a sine wave?

Comment: The answer depends on diode's parameters, diode's biasing, and the current's (voltage's) amplitude and frequency. Please show the schematic or, at least, describe the setup you have in mind.

Comment: Do you mean "AC voltage", as in applying a sinusoidal voltage to the junction? Or do you truly mean a constant current source?

Comment: Your second sentence make no sense.  You said you are applying a current to a diode, then you ask what type of current it is.  How can we tell, *you* are the one supplying the current.

Answer (score 3):

> What would happen if a AC current is applied to a PN junction?

Although that may sound reasonable, taken literally, it is problematic.  Consider the following circuit that literally realizes what is asked:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8SkpC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When the current is clockwise (positive polarity), all is well (assuming the PN junction can tolerate the amount of current).

However, when the current source reverses polarity and tries to circulate current counter-clockwise, the PN junction *must* break down to allow the current to circulate.

But, I doubt this is what you had in mind.  Please add a schematic and any additional constraints if this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Shouldn't this be just a comment, asking whether he truly means "current"?

Comment: @Mels: No, this is actually the correct answer. +1

Comment: I never questioned the validity of the answer, _presuming this was indeed what the OP meant_ (which still hasn't been made clear. When an answer starts with "I'm not sure what you have in mind (...)", that usually indicates that the question should be cleared up first by asking for additional explanation in a comment. That makes both question and answer much more readable to someone who finds it later on.

Comment: @Mels, I perfectly understand your concern but do consider that it *may* be valuable to the OP to understand, *via a diagram*, what has been asked.  Also, I've invited the OP to revise and clarify and, if the OP obliges, I will update my answer appropriately.

Comment: Okay, you got me convinced. Downvote is locked though, can't remove it unless you edit. Could you do that?

Comment: There you go =)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the OP believes that p-n junction *can't* admit backward current, and must cut it off, while a current source must supply the current, which looks paradoxically.

(From now on I'll talk about diode, since the easiest way to apply current to a p-n junction is making Ohmic contacts to its both sides, which results in a diode)

For an ideal rectifying diode connected to an ideal current source it's true, and connecting it this way would be a nonsense since current source would create infinite backward voltage and still not make any current.

But real diode does have a breakdown voltage, at which it starts to admit backward current (and it's a working mode of a Zener diode). OTOH, real current source will stop supplying nominal current when output voltage required exceeds some maximum value.

Thus it depends on which of the devices is closer to ideal, i.e. which value is higher: diode breakdown voltage or current source max output voltage. If current source max output voltage is higher, then yes, input current is a sine wave. Otherwise, it is a sine wave clipped from below.